# Apache Pig: DEFINE STREAM Error using Python code

Tags: python, apache-pig, python-2.6

I am practising Apache Pig. Using DEFINE and STREAM operator I want to stream a file using python script and get as some edited output.

```
Below is the file I am using.

[cloudera@localhost ~]$ cat data/movies_data.csv 
1,The Nightmare Before Christmas,1993,3.9,4568
2,The Mummy,1932,3.5,4388
3,Orphans of the Storm,1921,3.2,9062
4,The Object of Beauty,1991,2.8,6150
5,Night Tide,1963,2.8,5126
6,One Magic Christmas,1985,3.8,5333
7,Muriels Wedding,1994,3.5,6323
8,Mothers Boys,1994,3.4,5733
9,Nosferatu Original Version,1929,3.5,5651
10,Nick of Time,1995,3.4,5333
```

The output I expected from pig using Python is first field value multiple with 10, second field data convert to UPPER CASE and third field year increase by 1.

Expected sample output:

```
10,THE NIGHTMARE BEFORE CHRISTMAS,1994,3.9,4568
20,THE MUMMY,1933,3.5,4388
```

My Python code that I used in

```
[cloudera@localhost ~]$cat testpy22.py

#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import string

for line in sys.stdin:
    (f1,f2,f3,f4,f5)=str(line).strip().split(",")
    f1 = f1*10
    f2 = f2.upper()
    f3 = f3+1

    print"%d\t%s\t%d\t%.2f\t%d"%(f1,f2,f3,f4,f5)
```

And below are the Pig code that I am trying:

```
grunt> a = load '/home/cloudera/data/movies_data.csv' using PigStorage(',') as (id:chararray,movie:chararray,year:chararray, point:chararray,code:chararray);

grunt> dump a;       

Output(s):
Successfully stored records in: "file:/tmp/temp-947273140/tmp1180787799"

Job DAG:
job_local1521960706_0008


2017-07-15 04:56:26,250 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Success!
2017-07-15 04:56:26,250 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleBackend - SchemaTupleBackend has already been initialized
2017-07-15 04:56:26,251 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat - Total input paths to process : 1
2017-07-15 04:56:26,251 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.util.MapRedUtil - Total input paths to process : 1
(1,The Nightmare Before Christmas,1993,3.9,4568)
(2,The Mummy,1932,3.5,4388)
(3,Orphans of the Storm,1921,3.2,9062)
(4,The Object of Beauty,1991,2.8,6150)
(5,Night Tide,1963,2.8,5126)
(6,One Magic Christmas,1985,3.8,5333)
(7,Muriels Wedding,1994,3.5,6323)
(8,Mothers Boys,1994,3.4,5733)
(9,Nosferatu Original Version,1929,3.5,5651)
(10,Nick of Time,1995,3.4,5333)


grunt> DEFINE testpy22 `testpy22.py` SHIP('/home/cloudera/testpy22.py');

grunt> aaa = STREAM a through testpy22;               

grunt> dump aaa;
```

When I dump the data, I am getting following error. I assume the error is due to Python code. But I am not able to find the issue.

```
2017-07-15 04:58:37,718 [pool-9-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigRecordReader - Current split being processed file:/home/cloudera/data/movies_data.csv:0+344
2017-07-15 04:58:37,736 [pool-9-thread-1] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration - dfs.https.address is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.namenode.https-address
2017-07-15 04:58:37,755 [pool-9-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleBackend - Key [pig.schematuple] was not set... will not generate code.
2017-07-15 04:58:37,787 [pool-9-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigMapOnly$Map - Aliases being processed per job phase (AliasName[line,offset]): M: a[6,4],a[-1,-1],aaa[10,6] C:  R: 
===== Task Information Header =====
Command: testpy22.py (stdin-org.apache.pig.builtin.PigStreaming/stdout-org.apache.pig.builtin.PigStreaming)
Start time: Sat Jul 15 04:58:37 PDT 2017
Input-split file: file:/home/cloudera/data/movies_data.csv
Input-split start-offset: 0
Input-split length: 344
=====          * * *          =====
2017-07-15 04:58:37,855 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - HadoopJobId: job_local1407418523_0009
2017-07-15 04:58:37,855 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Processing aliases a,aaa
2017-07-15 04:58:37,855 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - detailed locations: M: a[6,4],a[-1,-1],aaa[10,6] C:  R: 
2017-07-15 04:58:37,857 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 0% complete
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cloudera/testpy22.py", line 7, in <module>
    f1,f2,f3,f4,f5=str(line).strip().split(",")
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
2017-07-15 04:58:37,913 [Thread-98] ERROR org.apache.pig.impl.streaming.ExecutableManager - 'testpy22.py ' failed with exit status: 1
2017-07-15 04:58:37,914 [Thread-94] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner - Map task executor complete.
2017-07-15 04:58:37,917 [Thread-99] ERROR org.apache.pig.impl.streaming.ExecutableManager - testpy22.py (stdin-org.apache.pig.builtin.PigStreaming/stdout-org.apache.pig.builtin.PigStreaming) failed with exit status: 1
===== Task Information Footer =====
End time: Sat Jul 15 04:58:37 PDT 2017
Exit code: 1
Input records: 10
Input bytes: 3568 bytes (stdin using org.apache.pig.builtin.PigStreaming)
Output records: 0
Output bytes: 0 bytes (stdout using org.apache.pig.builtin.PigStreaming)
=====          * * *          =====
2017-07-15 04:58:37,921 [Thread-94] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner - job_local1407418523_0009
java.lang.Exception: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2055: Received Error while processing the map plan: 'testpy22.py ' failed with exit status: 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:406)
Caused by: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2055: Received Error while processing the map plan: 'testpy22.py ' failed with exit status: 1
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapBase.runPipeline(PigGenericMapBase.java:311)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapBase.cleanup(PigGenericMapBase.java:124)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:142)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:672)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:330)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:268)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
2017-07-15 04:58:42,875 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Ooops! Some job has failed! Specify -stop_on_failure if you want Pig to stop immediately on failure.
2017-07-15 04:58:42,877 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - job job_local1407418523_0009 has failed! Stop running all dependent jobs
2017-07-15 04:58:42,877 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 100% complete
2017-07-15 04:58:42,878 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.PigStatsUtil - 1 map reduce job(s) failed!
2017-07-15 04:58:42,878 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.SimplePigStats - Detected Local mode. Stats reported below may be incomplete
2017-07-15 04:58:42,879 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.SimplePigStats - Script Statistics: 

HadoopVersion   PigVersion  UserId  StartedAt   FinishedAt  Features
2.0.0-cdh4.7.0  0.11.0-cdh4.7.0 cloudera    2017-07-15 04:58:37 2017-07-15 04:58:42 STREAMING

Failed!

Failed Jobs:
JobId   Alias   Feature Message Outputs
job_local1407418523_0009    a,aaa   STREAMING,MAP_ONLY  Message: Job failed!    file:/tmp/temp-947273140/tmp1217312985,

Input(s):
Failed to read data from "/home/cloudera/data/movies_data.csv"

Output(s):
Failed to produce result in "file:/tmp/temp-947273140/tmp1217312985"

Job DAG:
job_local1407418523_0009


2017-07-15 04:58:42,879 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Failed!
2017-07-15 04:58:42,881 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias aaa
Details at logfile: /home/cloudera/pig_1500117064292.log
grunt> 2017-07-15 04:58:43,685 [communication thread] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner -
```

Can any body give me any suggestion?

Python version: 2.6.6
Apache Pig version: Apache Pig version 0.11.0-cdh4.7.0

Comment: [Python 2.6? wow](http://imgur.com/hiX84mb)

Comment: @idjaw 2.6.6 that comes default with CDH.

Comment: If you have control over it, upgrade that version of Python.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are running into is when you're unpacking the list directly into a series of values e.g. the "tuple unpacking" feature of python:

```
f1, f2, f3, f4, f5 = str(line).strip().split(",")
```

Python will throw an error if the split(",") function returns anything **other** than 5 variables. My guess is you are hitting a blank line...

> ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Definitely upgrade Python to 2.7, but this is core functionality and the version is not impacting you.